# Why is the average of my user defined array incorrect? C

Tags: c, arrays, function-prototypes

When this program gives back the average, it is zero every time, am I not passing values correctly to the average() function? I don't know what to fix, as I have tried switching data types and outputting %f too.
I don't want the code done for me, just need some guidance. Thanks any one that can help.

```
    #include <stdio.h>



float average(float arr[], float num) {

for (z = 0; z < num; ++z) {
    sum = arr[z]+1;
}

    avg = sum / num;

    return avg;

}

int main(){
    int count;
    int a;
    float initial[a];
    float avg;
    avg = average( initial, a);
    printf("enter number of values you'd like averaged.\n ");
    scanf("%i",&a);
    count = a;
    printf("enter numbers you'd like averaged\n");
    for(a= 0; a < count; a++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&initial[a]);
    }
    printf("The average is %d",avg);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is unreadable. Indent&format the code properly.

Comment: I don't see any average calculated. It is just adding ones to array elements..

Comment: Your average function is wrong. It will always return `(arr[num] + 1) / num`.

Comment: Hey thanks everyone, look I don't think all the down votes were necessary, if you were new at this like me, the question and the responses would be pretty informative to someone trying to do something similar ..js. My mistake on the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems. In this section of the code:

```
for (z = 0; z < num; ++z) {
   sum = arr[z]+1;
}
```

You are not calculating or initializing the sum, you are calculating the last element plus 1. Use:

```
float sum = 0, avg;
for (z = 0; z < num; ++z) {
   sum += arr[z];
}
```

As well as this you are not filling your array before calculating the average. There are also various other problems. Here is a live example of it working. http://ideone.com/5nOV81

Comment: Yeah this took care of it, wasn't that broken after all, though to real coders any mistake is probably unacceptable. Got me past a real sticking point, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In `main` call your function after getting values into the array (*right now array is uninitialized*)-

```
for(a= 0; a < count; a++)
{
   scanf("%f",&initial[a]);
}
avg = average( initial, a); 
printf("The average is %f",avg); 
                       ^^ note specifier is %f not %d as you used
```

And in your function `average` instead of this -

```
sum = arr[z]+1;
```

do -

```
sum+= arr[z];  //initliaze sum to 0 before loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result is always zero because you are calling the average method before even reading the variable `a` and the array `initial`...

```
avg = average( initial, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have several mistakes

that will be sum += arr[z];
and you have to initialize sum as 0

```
sum=0;

for (z = 0; z < num; ++z) {
 sum += arr[z];
}
```

you have to call function average after reading all numbers

```
for(a= 0; a < count; a++)
{
scanf("%f",&initial[a]);
}
avg = average(initial, a);
```

though return type of average is float so you have to use %f in printf

```
printf("The average is %f",avg);
```